# GPIO not producing power but gpio readall says it should

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, rpi.gpio

I have Raspberry Pi 3 model B, running RaspbianOS.

I was trying to work with GPIO, but the pins were not producing power.

I was using RPi.GPIO library in python to turn on and off the pins. I tried all GPIO user pins, but with no luck.

I can be sure it's not problem of the components I try to connect, because when I plug it to 5V power supply, it works properly.

The weird thing is, that if I execute gpio readall command, it produces the correct states for what I try to achieve, but there's no voltage on the GPIO pin, but the gpio readall says, there should be:

```
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 |   IN | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 |   IN | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 0 |  7 || 8  | 0 | IN   | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | IN   | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI |   IN | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO |   IN | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK |   IN | 0 | 23 || 24 | 0 | IN   | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 0 | IN   | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 0 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     | 
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 0 | 31 || 32 | 1 | OUT  | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |  OUT | 1 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

GPIO.26 is in mode OUT and V is 1, but when I try to plug my cooler in this, it doesn't work (again, I checked the cooler, it works when I plug it to 5V/3V power supply pin).

Is there anything I am forgetting, or doing wrongly?

I have also ran gpio pintest, and no error reported.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add data/reference for cooler.

Comment: I suspect that the cooler wants to draw more current than available via the GPIO port. The current output from the 3V3 rail should be limited to 50 mA. If you need more, which I suspect you need, use a MOSFET.

Comment: @steviethecat while this is a poor question, posting unfounded "facts" does not help. The Pi3 3.3V rail can easily supply 800mA, although drawing more than 16mA from a GPIO pin exceeds recommended limits.